# Join drive button and input: file for local files

Tags: google-drive-api

So: how can I use the drive button: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive and load a selected local file from an input: file so that I can save it in the cloud?

I understand that the button loads a file that is hosted on another host by putting its url in the button, but I need to save a local file, and from "input: file" put it in "data-url" or where it is correct to upload the file (images in my case)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Save to Drive Demo: Explicit Render</title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="GDrive" 
          name="GDrive" 
          enctype="multipart/form-data" 
          method="post">

        <input  type="file" 
                onChange="renderSaveToDrive('savetodrive-div', this.files[0].name,'GDrive');">
        <div id="savetodrive-div"></div>
    </form>
    <script>
        function renderSaveToDrive(namediv, namefile, idfrm) {

            console.log('namediv: ' + namediv + ' nameFile: ' + namefile);

            window.___gcfg = {
                lang: 'es-ES',
                parsetags: 'explicit'
            };
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var fd = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem(idfrm));
            fd.append("file_new_name", namefile);
            xhr.open("POST", location.href);
            xhr.send(fd);       
            gapi.savetodrive.render(namediv, {
              src: namefile,
              filename: namefile,
              sitename: 'GDrive Demo: Explicit Render'
            });
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried before and/or add more information

Comment: ready, please help me